# Why I can not access my application using Application Name

Tags: facebook

I have created a facebook application for "App on Facebook" and "Website"
I am able to access the application by using the following url - http://apps.facebook.com/{app-id}/

I just want to know what do I need to do in order to access the same by its name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the name in the `App Namespace:` field, which is in the Basic Info section for your App.

[image: namespace]

Comment: If your app name is really unique, then yes. Unique - just like any username, for example. Facebook will give you an error message if you can't use the name you have chosen.